# Adding programmes to Windows 10 startup through Task manager

Tags: windows-10, boot, scheduled-tasks, task-manager

I am well aware that when I want to make a programme run on startup under Windows, I am supposed to add a shortcut to the following folder:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

However, there is also the Startup tab in the Task Manager, where one can enable/disable specific applications running on startup. I like this better because it gives me a single, logical location to control this.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find any way of adding/removing programmes manually. When an app asks me whether I want to run it from startup and I confirm, I presume it changes something in the registries and the app appears in the list within the Task Manager.

Is there a way for me to modify the Startup list within the Task Manager directly, or do I need to go through the registries? Or do I really need to manage this using that silly folder?

Comment: Programs that ask you if you want it to start with windows are automatically added to that list after a reboot. If you don't receive that option (Outlook for example), you will need to pop a shortcut in that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel comfortable modifying the registry yourself (always make a backup first), you can add the program that way.

1. Open the Start Menu and type `regedit`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Use the directory structure on the left to navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.
3. Right click on "Run" in the folder tree.
4. Highlight *New* and click *String Value*
5. Type the name of the program in the *Name* field that becomes active and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Double click the new entry and enter the full filepath to the program you want to have run at startup (including quotation marks `"` if the path contains any spaces).
7. Click OK.

It should then show up in Task Manager and also run when you restart your computer.